# Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named pinax

Tags: python, django, pinax

I'm trying to get pinax working on WebFaction and having so many issues...

```
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=22796): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/myproject.wsgi'.
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup()
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __init__
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Sun Feb 19 20:01:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named pinax
```

The wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

The wsgi is in the same folder as myproject and settings.py is definitely in myproject. So what gives?

EDIT:

Okay so I took the advice from here as well as from webfaction and the wsgi now looks like this...

```
import os
import sys
from site import addsitedir
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
sys.path.append('/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/myproject')
sys.path.append('/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial')

addsitedir('/home/pawesome/envs/pinax072/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
application = WSGIHandler()
```

I think this has solved something but not everything... now I am getting...

```
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=15572): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/myproject.wsgi'.
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/lib/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Sun Feb 19 20:00:28 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_openid.consumer: "No module named voting_extras"
```

Thanks again guys... The people at WebFaction have recently given up and told me to come here even though I already had lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were 2 issues,

1. The virtualenv should be loaded in ~/apache2/bin/start with these lines,

   `WORKON_HOME=/home/pawesome/envs/pinax072/
   . $WORKON_HOME/bin/activate`
2. You should be using the wsgi file provided by pinax and not the one our installer provides as pinax has some custom path code that is needed,

   `#WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/myproject.wsgi`
   `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/myproject/deploy/pinax.wsgi`

Answer (score 20):

In your terminal, cd into the directory that contains settings.py, then run

```
python settings.py
```

You may get an import error that is easily fixed (typing error, or syntax error).

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried to add that folder to your PYTHONPATH explicitly? Also, you may need to add **both** the project folder and the parent one. Add these lines to your wsgi file, using the path of your project:

```
sys.path.append('/explicit/path/to/myproject')
sys.path.append('/explicit/path/to')
```

P.S. do that before the `application = WSGIHandler()`line.

**Update**: the new error seems to have the same cause, according to [this](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/1235/pinax-installation-no-module-named-groupsbase-image-displaying-problem). Please double-check where your "voting_extras" app is, and whether or not its parent folder is present in the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Okay so I took the advice from here as well as from webfaction and the wsgi now looks like this...

import os
import sys
from site import addsitedir
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
sys.path.append('/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial/myproject')
sys.path.append('/home/pawesome/webapps/qtsocial')

addsitedir('/home/pawesome/envs/pinax072/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
application = WSGIHandler()

Comment: @milktrey updated the answer based on some info from webfaction, I hope it helps...

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to add your stuff to the PYTHONPATH. I add my project and it's virtualenv.
Here is a sample of what your wsgi could look like per project.

```
import sys
import site
import os

envpath = '/development/myproject/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

# we add currently directory to path and change to it
pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(pwd)
sys.path = [pwd] + sys.path

# Append paths
site.addsitedir(envpath)

# now start django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv just add path to your site package and python site-packages directory in Apache config or your site config (outside VirtualHost directive)

`WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python2.X/site-packages`

For me, it was:

`WSGIPythonPath /var/www/djtest:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter a similar problem. In my case I had a top level config folder, where general **settings.py** file was located. In **myproject** folder I had a second settings where I try to import **config.settings** file.

In my case the problem was that python was looking in **myproject.config** folder instead of **top level config**.

```
    # project structure
    config/
        settings.py
        constans.py
    myproject/
        config/
            constants.py
        settings.py
        manage.py
        urls.py
```

> err: ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is
>   it on sys.path?): No module named settings

**Solution**: I removed/moved the **myproject/config** folder.

Answer (score -1):

with Pycharm. I closed "Add content roots to PYTHONATH" and "Add source roots to PYTHONATH". It works.