# How do I add my production_settings in sys.path manually to run syncdb?

Tags: django

On the production server I would like to sync the db.

If I just did that

`django-admin.py syncdb` it would pick the settings.py. But I have an extra settings-production.py that inheritcs from settings.

Hence I came up with this:

```
django-admin.py syncdb --settings=/path/to/settings_production
```

> ImportError: Could not import settings
>   '/path/to/settings_production' (Is it on
>   sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.

I googled and found someone had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353092/could-not-import-settings-myproject-settings-is-it-on-sys-path-no-module-n). However something that confuses me is, the WSGI.py is only read by Apache. Not if I ran the command myself.  The answer there doesn't really make sense to me.

How do I add my production_settings in sys.path manually to run syncdb?
Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First make sure `settings_production.py` is in the same directory as `settings.py`.*

Since you are inheriting from settings you can add at the bottom of `settings.py`:

```
try:
   from settings_production import *
except ImportError:
   pass
```

If you want to *only* use `settings_production.py` make sure it has all the settings for your application (database, et. al.) then:

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_production python manage.py syncdb`

***Edit***

*I was going to post it as a comment, but it became too long:*

I did it this way because typically in production one only changes a few values you can import in the master `settings.py`; and the last value of the variable is used (so if you set production db in `settings_production.py`, then that setting is used).

It is easier this way since django by default will look for `settings.py`; avoids having to deal with environment variables and import paths especially if you are changing minor things.

There are a few draw backs to this approach; for example I can't imagine its very portable especially if you have multiple environments (staging/testing/production/dev), as then you have multiple `from _foo_ import *` statements and it can lead to problems because the order of imports becomes significant; if you forgot and kept around a stray `settings_*.py` around - for example the test environment also got the dev file because some developer forgot to remove it from the test branch.

For more complex setups its easier to keep *complete copies* of the master `settings.py` file; and then point `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the python path of those files. The caveat here is that you have to make sure `PYTHONPATH` is adjusted to include the location of your settings.

For more ideas, see the [SplitSettings wiki entry](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings).

Comment: Thanks Burhan, according to http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/ under Using Different Settings for Production it is the settings_production.py that imports from settings `from settings import *` You seem to do it the other way around, no?