# ImportError: Could not import settings... No module named settings?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.

I've encountered this issue before, but was able to work around it by adding the parent directory to sys.path using this code:

```
import sys

def rtrim(s, sep):
    return sep.join(s.split(sep)[0:-1])

sys.path.insert(0, rtrim(sys.path[0], '/'))

from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

Today, seemingly out of nowhere, it reared its ugly head once more. The directory structure is as follows:

```
Ingest/
  settings.py
  ingest/ (current working directory)
    test.py
```

[image]

Here are sys.path and part of the Traceback:

```
['/mnt/c/Users/Travis/Documents/GitHub/{redacted}/Ingest', '/mnt/c/Users/Travis/Documents/GitHub/{redacted}/Ingest/ingest', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'Ingest.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

As you can see, the parent directory is in sys.path.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you verify if `from django.conf import settings` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not certain as to why this worked initially, for over a month, and then broke, seemingly for no reason, but after a couple hours of Googling I finally found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19741994/9343059

> Last option, if your manage.py and settings.py reside in same
>   location, change environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to
>   settings instead of myProject.settings, or run python manage.py with
>   --settings=settings arguments

I was able to fix the issue by replacing

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

with

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```