# Django ImportError: Could not import settings

Tags: python, django, importerror

I am getting following error. Before git pull and merge, everything was working fine. I checked the history to find removal of any files etc.

- I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353092/could-not-import-settings-myproject-settings-is-it-on-sys-path-no-module-n). I have checked other ans on stackoverflow but, it didn't solve the problem.
- I have checked `sys.path`.  Project directory path is present in `sys.path`.
- Someone mentioned to verify `__init__.py` file in `myapp` folder. It is present.
- Bootstrap3 package is installed in system.
- I ran `python setup.py develop` again.

Not sure how to debug this?

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myapp.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named bootstrap3
```

Comment: is the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE properly set in your environnement ?

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? Is it activated? Are there all required modules installed (```pip freeze``` should return list of installed modules).

Answer (score 3):

You are using `bootstrap3` and its might be not installed or not in `PYTHONPATH`.

Original error is `No module named bootstrap3`, please check for `bootstrap3` module.

Comment: I think he mention that `Bootstrap3 package is installed in system.`

Comment: will you please try `import bootstrap3` in python console ?

Comment: This is unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: `bootstrap3` is installed in system. I m not sure but, build got corrupted. Merging process had deleted many files under build directory. May be that's the reason. Re-running `python setup.py develop` didn't solve the problem. So I took last bold option of fresh installation. And then everything is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install requirements.txt and it will be ok !
run this command in your shell:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: There can be no requirements.txt.

Comment: why not? i installed it right now and the problem solved